# Derivative of Delta dirac integral

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I have a problem with this integral:
$I=\int\limits_{ - 5}^5 ( x^2 - 4 )^9 \delta^{(9)} (x + 2) \, dx $

I did it as this:
Use Newton expansion: ${\left( {{x^2} - 4} \right)^9} = {x^{18}} - 9.4{x^{16}} + {36.4^2}{x^{14}} - {84.4^3}.{x^{12}} + {126.4^4}.{x^{10}} - {126.4^5}.{x^8}{\rm{ + 84}}{.4^6}.{x^6} - {36.4^7}.{x^4} + {9.4^8}.{x^2} - {4^9}$
Then, I used formula: 
$\int \left[ x^n f (x) \right] \delta ^{\left( n \right)}(x) \,dx  = (-1)^n n! \int f(x)\delta (x) \, dx $

And the final result:  $I=0$  (Wrong or Right??)

But my teacher said I should do it agian??

Thanks my friends!!!

Comment: Does $\delta(x)$ denote Dirac function?

Comment: Yes, this case,derivative (9) of Dirac function

Comment: This is extraordinarily bad MathJax usage style!  You must be using one of those software packages that "help" you with MathJax code.

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac function have the following property:
\begin{equation}
\int_a^bf(x)\delta^{(n)}(x-c)dx=(-1)^nf^{(n)}(x)|_{x=c}\quad a<c<b
\end{equation}
So your problem can be solved by:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-5}^5(x^2-4)^9\delta^{(9)}(x+2)dx=(-1)^9[(x^2-4)^9]^{(9)}|_{x=-2}=95126814720
\end{equation}

About $[(x^2-4)^9]^{(9)}$
We can use binomial expansion theorem:
\begin{equation}
(x^2-4)^9=\sum_{n=0}^9C_9^nx^{2n}(-4)^{9-n}
\end{equation}
Then the derivative is 
\begin{equation}
[(x^2-4)^9]^{(9)}=(\sum_{n=0}^9C_9^nx^{2n}(-4)^{9-n})^{(9)}=\sum_{n=5}^9C_9^n(x^{2n})^{(9)}(-4)^{9-n}\\
=\sum_{n=5}^9C_9^n(A_{2n}^9x^{2n-9})(-4)^{9-n}
\end{equation}
where $C_n^m$ is number of permutation and $A_n^m$ is number of arrangement.

Comment: #Lion Thank you so much, but my problem I'm facing that is: Calculating derivate 9 times of (x^2-4)^9!!! Could you give me more details

Comment: @MacArthurNguyen I add them in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Lion very much!!!! ;))

Comment: @MacArthurNguyen That is my pleasure.